# Test and Verify AWS Redis Integration with Django project

Tags: django, redis, amazon-elasticache

I am new to Django. I was trying to implement Redis cache system into my Django project. I am using AWS free tier to host my Django project on EC2 machine using gunicorn web server and trying to integrate AWS Redis Cache. I have added below entry in my settings.py file:

```
CACHE = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND' : "redis_cache.cache.RedisCache",
        'LOCATION' : "redis://xxx.xxx.xxxxx.cache.amazonaws.com/1",
        'OPTIONS' : {
            'CLIENT_CLASS' : 'redis_cache.client.DefaultClient',
            
        },
    }
}
```

And below is my view function:

```
def usertable(request):
    obj = userdetails.objects.get(id=1)
    name = obj.name
    if cache.get(name):
        cache_name = cache.get(name)
        print ("From CACHE")
    else:
        cache_name = obj.name
        cache.set(name, cache_name)
        print ("*****************FROM DB********************")
   context = {
        'name' : cache_name,
       }
```

This code is working for me and I can see From CACHE printed in my terminal. But the key value pair which is set if I manually connect to redis using below cli tool:
redis-cli -h xx.xx.xxxxx…cache.amazonaws.com -p 6379 -n 1
on giving keys * I do not see any key value pair is set.

I am not sure if this is the correct way to test integration of Redis cache. Kindly advice if anyone had tried Redis Cache system.

Comment: When you set the cache, try adding a timeout - `cache.set(name, cache_name, 600)`

Comment: I had tried both ways. added CACHE_TTL  in settings.py and also in cache.set function. But still I do not see key value pair in my AWS Elasticache Redis